# Не приходят данные методом POST от банка

Tags: python, php, ruby, perl

Здравствуйте. От банка должен приходить ответ об успешной оплате пользователя методом POST на конкретный url нашего сайта. Проблема в том, что у банка не получается отправить данные методом пост на наш сайт в то время как я отправляю данные с со своей машины и все принимается и обрабатывается отлично.

Может ли быть это связано с настройками моего хостинга или причина в другом? Отправил вопрос провайдеру думают уже очень давно(тупят, не как не могу вникнуть в мой элементарный вопрос). Банковский админ утверждает что у него выходит при отправке некая ошибка: error: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Использую: шаред хостинг, Linux, apache, PHP/Yii framework.

В чем может быть дело? 
Спасибо.

Comment: я вас поздравляю, банковский админ - и.. некомпетентен в общем.

java.lang.NullPointerException. - это может быть чем угодно.

Comment: Не советую вам продолжать работать с этим банком.

Comment: Поделитесь названием банка, что-ли)

Comment: @AlexDenisov - почти любой, уровень качества софта в банках просто поражает воображение.

Comment: Это Казкоммерцбанк. Это Казахстан, коллеги. Есть еще один банк, но это шило на мыло.

Comment: Скиньте админу какую-нибудь курловую команду, пусть выполнит и даст вам ее вывод. Это поможет диагностировать проблему.

Comment: Все-таки чтобы окончательно развеять мои сомнения может ли это быть связано с настройками моего хостера? А то я в админоских тонкостях не силен. Банк утверждает видите ли я один такой из тясячи магазинов, который их использует.

Comment: узнаю родной казахстан)) если хотите помочь админу, то скажите пусть скинет лог ошибки, надеюсь хотя бы это они умеют, и уже от этого можно будет плясать... у меня такая была ошибка на сайте самрука, но это ошибка на стороне клиента, а не сервера, проблема оказалась в том что надо было загрузить сертификат в java - client authentication, у них может быть все что угодно

Comment: есть такое гадание - ошибка эта вылетает если какой-то объект не создался на стороне банка (отдельный привет программисту который не перехватил ошибку и не выдал  вменяемое сообщение) на вашей стороне это может быть:

 * файрвол
 * если соединение  https, то на стороне банка, может быть ваш провайдер сертификата неизвестен (старые списки), или у вас самоподписанный сертификат и банк его не любит.
 * банк требует какой-то ответ, типа json или xml, ваш не валидный
 * ваш сервер почему-то обрывает соединение

Comment: Сбросьте ему ссылку на этот вопрос - вместе посмотрим что можно сделать, будет, однако, быстрее)

Comment: Он отправляет через браузер все работает. Отправляет данные через их клиент не получается и ошибочка. Очевидно проблема на их стороне и на их клиенте?

Comment: перепроверьте все, то что касается 3го и второго пункта. возможно (по третьему пункту) не хватает (или наоборот лишний) перевод строки в конце ответа. (в вашем сервере, то вообще какой нить запрос появляется в логах например ?), используйте tshark, чтобы посмотреть приходит ли вам хоть какой-то пакет от банка.

Comment: не удивлюсь если все впишут на выросший сегодня курс доллара))

Comment: Да так и есть: "Нам не до вас, курс, работы выше крыши" и т.п. Еще у них там один единственный админ на всю страну.

Answer (score 2):

какой бы не была причина - в любом случае это ошибка нашего любимого Казкоммерцбанка.

во-первых, клиент всегда прав

во-вторых, это нонсенс - чтобы банк не знал в чем дело. выдавать в эфир "error: java.lang.NullPointerException" и демагогию: "у всех работает, а у вас нет" - показатель сверх непрофессионализма. "NullPointerException" - это не причина, а следствие возникшей ошибки. причина может быть: 1) руки (и мозги) не из того места у программистов ККБ (больше всего к этом склоняюсь) 2) фаервол, либо разрыв связи 3) проблема с сертификатом (eicto более грамотно расписал возможные причины конечно). но в этом случае они должны были озвучивать именно это, а не демагогические нульпоинтерэксепшн. если причина с вашей стороны, то должны были выдать инструкции как это исправить.

в-третьих, POST он и в Казахстане POST, провайдеры тут не при чем. и тупят не провайдеры, а сотрудники банка.

в-четвертых, не удивляйтесь ничему - это Казахстан, родственные связи и т.д.